# Script Installation Problems RP 2 | iojs | node | npm

Tags: apt, script

I am trying to install this Script on my RaspberryPi 2 with wheezy on it. I think I am having problems installing npm.

Here is the [script](http://git.io/vk13W):

```bash
if [[ "$USER" != 'root' ]]; then
  echo "Sorry, you need to run this as as root"
  exit   
fi 

apt-get update
apt-get upgrade -y
apt-get install -y git wget tar build-essential libssl-dev  

cd ~
mkdir tmp
cd tmp

# Install iojs
wget https://iojs.org/dist/v1.6.1/iojs-v1.6.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
tar --strip-components 1 -xzvf iojs-v* -C /usr/local

# Clone steamboosthours repository
git clone https://github.com/frk1/steamhourboost.git ~/steamboosthours
cd ~/steamboosthours

# Run npm install
npm install .
npm install -g coffee-script forever

echo "~ Installation finished ~"
```

I think I have to change the iojs version to an version for the arm71 architecture.

Could somebody edit this script for me, so it will work on an Raspberry Pi, I am at the end of my knowledge :/

Comment: Maybe it is possible to get this script working, but what is it you want to achieve, really? What is the purpose of running the script? Where did you get it?

Comment: What "problem" do you get running this script and how are you "installing" it? if you run all the commands manually do they do what you want? We need the commands you ran and the error messages as they appeared at the time.

Answer (score 1):

you should really provide more info, as noted in the comments; in particular: what's the output of the script when executed?

however, you can indeed "change the iojs version". i can't tell if this will help you achieve your ultimate goal, though. here you go:

```bash
if [[ "$USER" != 'root' ]]; then
  echo "Sorry, you need to run this as as root"
  exit   
fi 

apt-get update
apt-get upgrade -y
apt-get install -y git wget tar build-essential libssl-dev  

cd ~
mkdir tmp
cd tmp

# Install iojs
# wget https://iojs.org/dist/v1.6.1/iojs-v1.6.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
wget https://iojs.org/dist/v2.2.1/iojs-v2.2.1-linux-armv7l.tar.gz
tar --strip-components 1 -xzvf iojs-v* -C /usr/local

# Clone steamboosthours repository
git clone https://github.com/frk1/steamhourboost.git ~/steamboosthours
cd ~/steamboosthours

# Run npm install
npm install .
npm install -g coffee-script forever

echo "~ Installation finished ~"
```

this will download version 2.2.1 for architecture armv7l. however, you can browse https://iojs.org/dist/ and choose any version you see fit: simply copy one of the links to the archives, and paste it in the script after `wget`.

hope this helps,
bye

Comment: +1; but I think the answer could be improved slightly by including a little detail on why one would want to download the armv7l version instead of the x86.